Is there a way to copy files from VM to System.ArtifactsDirectory or Github Repository using Azure DevOps pipeline
New to creating YAML pipelines in Azure DevOps, Would appreciate any help!
I have a use case where I have to copy files from a VM to System.ArtifactsDirectory (and ultimately to GitHub Repo) using Azure DevOps pipeline.
I am aware there is a CopyFilesOverSSH@0 task which copies files from artifact directory to VM using ssh service connection. I want to do vice versa which above task does not allow

You can use SSH@0 - SSH v0 task to run shell commands or a script on a remote machine using SSH.
In the scripts,

Clone your GitHub repo to your VM using git clone.
Copy your target files into the repo's local folder.


For Windows, run copy sourcefolder destinationfolder
For Ubuntu, run cp sourcefolder destinationfolder


Run git commands to push the changes to your GitHub.


Is cloning the repo everytime pipeline is run efficient?

For the first pipeline run, you need to git clone the GitHub repo to your VM. Once the repo has been cloned, for subsequent pipeline runs, use git pull to get the latest updates. Then do step2 and step3.

Hi Ziyang I took your recommendation, the steps are working fine, just one query, while doing git clone i am running command
git clone "https://$(GITPAT)@github.com//.git" --branch=
This does clone the repo but pipeline still fails with error message -
##[error]Cloning into ''...

It's suggested that you can create a new question with the detailed debug error message. So that we can know more about your current issue and give you suggestions. Thanks.

Actually what i shared with you is the entire error message, there is nothing else visible

You can add a variable named system.debug and set the value to true. Then trigger the pipeline again and check if there is any detailed error message.

Did not help, it just repeated the same error message. As a workaround i unchecked the "fail on stderr" box now while errors are printed pipeline executes till end
